# my .so extension is not detected in php.ini

Tags: php, apache, configuration, v8

Im using MAC. My webserver is AMPPS with php.ini file at:

/Applications/AMPPS/php/etc/php.ini

I installed v8js using brew. all files were installed at:

```
/usr/local/
```

and the SO extension at:

```
/usr/local/opt/php56-v8js/v8js.so
```

I Include at my php.ini file the following information:

```
extension=/usr/local/opt/php56-v8js/v8js.so
```

no matter what I do, v8js is not running in my configuration.

one more thing, when I run on terminal php --ini the following information is displayed:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /usr/local/etc/php/5.6
Loaded Configuration File:         /usr/local/etc/php/5.6/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /usr/local/etc/php/5.6/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /usr/local/etc/php/5.6/conf.d/ext-v8js.ini
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, after nearly losing all my hair over this I discovered that I needed the `libc client` module.  HTH